# socket hangup multiple get calls in foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, get, fetch

Im trying to get multiple images from various URLs so im using forEach and fetch(url) together. I'm also trying to pipe them to a stream to save them to disk. The problem is after about 900 requests the request count slows down dramatically and eventually an error. Heres the code im using.

```
   const fetch = require('node-fetch')
   // savedImageURLS is an array of many image urls
   savedImageURLS.forEach((url) => {
      fetch(url).then((res) => {
        console.log(count)
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`images/image-${count++}.png`);
        res.body.pipe(dest)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('something went wrong', err)
      })
   })
```

I get this error:

```
something went wrong { FetchError: request to https://scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/0b261beb7775c9accecc15ef782c2d9e/5E51A24B/t51.2885-15/e35/66648821_222609615365883_2370330998081102527_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=103&se=7&ig_cache_key=MjA4NTI1NTY3NTY5Mjk0NDk3NA%3D%3D.2 failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Documents/batcave/instagram-saved-downloader/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
  message: 'request to https://scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/0b261beb7775c9accecc15ef782c2d9e/5E51A24B/t51.2885-15/e35/66648821_222609615365883_2370330998081102527_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=103&se=7&ig_cache_key=MjA4NTI1NTY3NTY5Mjk0NDk3NA%3D%3D.2 failed, reason: socket hang up'
```

I can't figure out whats going wrong. The image urls dont seem to be invalid. Is the get request not returning fast enough? am i running out of memory? Any help would be appreciated.

side note: I also tried this with node https.get(url) and got the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

While you are using node-fetch to make call for images, one thing should should be kept in mind is that it is promise based, meaning, it is asynchronous in nature. If you make N number of fetch calls, node requests for an I/O operation, thereby blocking a thread for your operation. If the number of threads allocated the node process exceeds, you'll always end up getting this error.

Also, requesting for 900 images using a forEach loop, is a bad idea. It is bound to choke your node queue. You can bread your requests into bursts of lets say X (X > 5 ) images of 900, and make 900/X calls in serial, and X calls in parallel (still won't recommend it).